# how do i get xml filesnames from local directory based on folder date modified

Tags: php, xml, file, directory

i need help to get xml files from local directory but only display xml filenames without extension. In my website i have installed content management system  which is generated pages as .xml extension but i want to display only xml filenames but based on folder date modified on latest post column in website.

**for example**

```
file name abc folder date modified 7/8/2014
file name xyz folder date modified 7/8/2013
```

but i want that system should automatically re arrange that file names based on folder date modified

**here my code but getting error**

```
$dir = "data/pages/";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

if (($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') ) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);  

$RGSostituzione = $xml->attributes()->Sostituzione;
echo "<li>File $file - <b>Sostituzione:</b> $RGSostituzione</li>";
}
}
closedir($dh);
}
}
```

**getting this error while getting file names from local directory**

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: 
.htaccess:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
```

what code should be apply that re arrange file names according to the file folder date modified please help me thanks in advance?

Comment: Regarding the error - you are aware of the fact that `readdir()` returns the filename, not the entire path, right? Shouldn't it be: `simplexml_load_file($dir.$file)`? If not that, check that your XML-files have the correct format and that they are actually contained in the $xml object. As for folder modification date, are you looking for something like [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)?

Comment: yes how do I use filemtime function?

Comment: You can basically read about it in the manual - first parameter is the path to the file, and in return, you get the modification date. You should try to use it along with `date()` to get a proper format. (Actually, I'll put all of this up as an answer soon, so it will be easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean the folder modification date or the file modification date (because to me, the second one makes more sense). Anyhow, to retrieve the file modfication date, you can use the [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function. This returns a date in forms of a Unix timestamp (as said in the manual page), and therefore you can use its return value as the second argument to the function `date()`, in order to retrieve the date in a format suiting to you. Do note though that you will get an E_WARNING unless you have used the `date_default_timezone_set()` function (when using the `date()` function).

```
$file_date = date("Y-m-d", filemtime("file.xml"));
```

To sort these, you can use an algorithm. Which one to choose depends entirely on which dateformat you use (and in worst case, you can always use `usort` to get a user-defined algorithm). If you simply use the format `Y-m-d`, then you can use the algorithm `sort()`, `asort()` or `ksort` (as well as the reverse ones, if that now would interest you) to sort the array depending on the date.

If I were you, I would put all the values retrieved from the directory into an array. You can manually put all the values into the array from your current while-loop, and later sort that one, or you can have a look at the `scandir()` function. Personally, I would do the following:

```
$temp = scandir($dir);
foreach ($temp  as $filename)
{
    if ($filename !== "." && $filename !== "..")
        $files[date("Y-m-d", filemtime($filename))] = $filename;
}
ksort($files);
```

The above will make `$files` contain an array of elements with filenames, sorted after the modification date (which are the keys of the array). Note that the precision of the above code only applies for days - if you want to be more thorough, you will have to use another date-format

Tell me if I've misunderstood anything, or if you have any further questions. As for the error part, I've taken that via comments.